# Having issues eliminating duplicates and sorting from C++ array outfile

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

Trying to create a list of unique grades from a text file.  Having issues with the output eliminating duplicates.  Currently, I am trying to compare the value of each previous array entry to the next and if they are different, output the result to the outfile, but is just outputs an empty file.

I am also curious if there is an easy fix to change the sorting from 'low to high' into 'high to low'.  Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int testScoreArray[100];
void selectSort(int testScoreArray[], int n);
void fileOutput(int testScoreArray[]);

int main()

{
    int n = 100;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("testscoresarrayhomework.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        infile >> testScoreArray[i];
    }

    selectSort(testScoreArray, n);
    fileOutput(testScoreArray);

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}

void selectSort(int testScoreArray[], int n)
{
    //pos_min is short for position of min
    int pos_min, temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        pos_min = i; //set pos_min to the current index of array

        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {

            if (testScoreArray[j] < testScoreArray[pos_min])
                pos_min = j;
            //pos_min will keep track of the index that min is in, this is needed when a swap happens
        }

        //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found, so a swap must occur
        if (pos_min != i) {
            temp = testScoreArray[i];
            testScoreArray[i] = testScoreArray[pos_min];
            testScoreArray[pos_min] = temp;
        }
    }
};

void fileOutput(int testScoreArray[])
{

    ofstream outfile;
    int gradeEvent = 0;
    int previousGrade = 0;

    outfile.open("testscoresoutput.txt");
    outfile << "Test Score Breakdown: ";
    outfile << endl
            << "Score / Occurance";

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        previousGrade = i;

        if (previousGrade && previousGrade != i) {

            outfile << '\n' << testScoreArray[i] << " / " << gradeEvent;
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
};
```

Comment: "[I]sn't working properly" is a very bad problem description. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Finally, unless your assignment is the sorting, then use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead. And [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) after sorting to remove duplicates.

Comment: ...and possibly replace the C-style arrays with vectors.

Comment: You need to [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) in order to review, line by line, the logic in `fileOutput()` which completely and totally broken. Afterwards, follow your rubber duck's instructions and everything should be fixed up in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a global variable `testScoreArray` and the function names use the same variable name for their parameters. It's best to avoid using global variables when possible. You can remove global declaration, then declare `testScoreArray` in main, and pass it to your functions. Example:

```
//int testScoreArray[100]; <=== comment out
void selectSort(int *testScoreArray, int n);
void fileOutput(int *testScoreArray, int n); //add array size

int main()
{
    int testScoreArray[100]; //<== add testScoreArray in here
    int n = sizeof(testScoreArray) / sizeof(testScoreArray[0]);
    selectSort(testScoreArray, n);
    fileOutput(testScoreArray, n);
    ...
}
```

In `fileOutput` you are basically checking to see if `i != i`, you need to examine the array, not indexing in the loop:

```
void fileOutput(int *testScoreArray, int n)
{
    ofstream outfile("testscoresoutput.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if(i && testScoreArray[i] != testScoreArray[i-1])
            outfile << testScoreArray[i] << "\n";
};
```

To revers the sort, simply change the condition in this comparison

```
if (testScoreArray[j] < testScoreArray[pos_min])
    pos_min = j;
```

To:

```
if(testScoreArray[j] > testScoreArray[pos_min])
    pos_min = j;
```

Technically you would rename the variable to `pos_max`